# Zip file is not getting generated as per day using log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have added jars apache-log4j-extras-1.1.jar and log4j-1.2.16.jar in classpath.Log is getting printed 
but zip or gz file is not getting generated. any solution on it??

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, request
    log4j.appender.request=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.request.File=path-to-logfolder/logs/File.log
    log4j.appender.request.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
    log4j.appender.request.RollingPolicy.ActiveFileName =path-to-logfolder/logs/File.log
    log4j.appender.request.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=path-to-logfolder/logs/File.%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.zip
    log4j.appender.request.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.request.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
    log4j.appender.request.Append = true
```

Comment: Where did you put the log4j configuration file?

Comment: I replaced log4j-1.2.16.jar with log4j-1.2.17.jar, it's working now

Comment: it's working for jar with seconds wise. what else I need so that it will generate gz file as per day

Comment: probably you can add answer yourself